# Best way to manage key-value pair in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, coding-style

There is a requirement. I have one excel import feature to add data to database from excel file. I need to add there a filter to check data before import. Let say there is a value like   **3:44-5:87-1:345** .
 Before import I need to validate this data are valid or not like-

->3, 5, 1 Should exist in table T1

->44, 87, 345, should exists in table T2.

If both condition match data should be validated as correct

Current code is like

```
string test = "3:44-5:87-1:345";
var attributes = test.Split(new[] { "-" },
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 if (attributes.Length != 0)
 {
     foreach (var attribute in attributes)
     {
         var attArray = attribute.Split(new[] { ":" },
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         if (attArray.Length >= 2)
         {
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(attArray[0].ToString())
             int value = Convert.ToInt32(attArray[1].ToString())

            //Call db to check if key exist
            if(KeyExist)
            {
             //Call db to check if value exist for the key
             if(ValueExist)
             {
             //CODE here to import data to datatabse
             }
            }
         }
     }

 }
```

For above sample data, it will make 3 call for 3 Key(3, 5,1) and 3 call for 3 Value(44, 87,345). So if there will be 100 of rows in excel sheet I may end up in Thousands of DB call. 
How to optimise it?

Comment: Is the combination of every `x` in `T1` to exactly one `y` in `T2` unique, or could one entry in `T1` be "connected" to several different entries in `T2` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Why not make a **Reader** Call in OleDB and store each result in a Dictionary<T,T> and then Iterate the Dictionary, That way you are doing only TWO Calls to check the Excel Sheets.

Comment: Depending on the answer, you could either work with two `Dictionaries` (`T1` => `T2` and `T2` => `T1`) or two `Lookups` (`T1` => `Group of T2` and `T2` => `Group of T1`)

Comment: 100 rows would be 200 db calls, not thousands.

Comment: @Corak, there will one to may relationship. So one entity of T1 will be connected to many Entity of T2

Comment: If by any chance you are also using Entity framework, this could be done way more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys and values occur multiple times in the Excel sheet you could speed up your logic by using dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, bool> keys = new Dictionary<int,bool>();
Dictionary<int, bool> values = new Dictionary<int,bool>();
string test = "3:44-5:87-1:345";
var attributes = test.Split(new[] { "-" },
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 if (attributes.Length != 0)
 {
     foreach (var attribute in attributes)
     {
         var attArray = attribute.Split(new[] { ":" },
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         if (attArray.Length >= 2)
         {
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(attArray[0].ToString())
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(attArray[1].ToString())

            if(!keys.Contains(key))
            {
                keys.Add(key, keyExists(key));
            }

            if(!values.Contains(value))
            {
                values.Add(value, valueExists(value));
            }

            if(keys[key])
            {
               if(values[value])
               {
                  //CODE here to import data to datatabse
               }
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

If your input string would be:

```
string test = "3:44-5:87-1:345-3:87-5:345-1:44";
```

The method using dictionaries would cut your database lookups in half compared to the original approach.

Comment: Where does `keyExists` and `valueExists` come from?  Assuming they are set to true this doesn't set the value to false when the key is seen a second time and thus doesn't change anything.  FYI a simple `HashSet` could be used to determine if a value has been seen before or not.

Comment: They are taken from OPs original code. I assume they are placeholders for a DB check. I will update my answer to make them method calls which hopefully makes it clearer.

Comment: Yeah, in that cause this would make more sense.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, keyExists and valueExists will be decided by DB call. If they already exists, why I will make a db call to check again

Comment: In this implementation, you would only make the call once and save the result. Whenever the same key or value is used, the result is taken from the dictionary and no DB call is necessary.

Comment: keyExists and valueExists, what is this. In my question these are 2 variable, returned from DB. If Key exist, it will return true else false and we can compare them in IF condition.

Comment: You didn't show the DB lookup code. So I had to improvise. Just create a lookup procedure for keys and one for values and use it like shown